# Linq query for Where condition on Collection of variant object's property

Tags: c#, linq, com-interop

I'm accessing an Interop model that has the following structure

> *Projects* is a collection containing multiple *Project* objects
>
> The *Project* object has a State property and a *Properties* collection
>
> The *Properties* collection contains *Variant/Object/Property* objects
>
> The *Property* always has a *Name* property

I want to use Linq to:

> <s>Find all Projects</s> Find the first Property object (1 or more projects may have a Property.Name == "InitiatorName". I just want the first Property Object that has Property.Name == "IntiatorName". That is I don't care which Project the Property Object belongs to.
>
> Where Project.State = state_initiated
>
> and the Project.Properties that have Project.Name = "InitiatorName"

Here is the Linq that I'm trying (which C# doesn't like)... I think I have the first couple of line correct, but I'm unsure how to deal with the variant Property objects.

Is there something I can do in Linq, or do I have to enumerate all of the property objects?

```
var result = dept.Projects
  .Cast<Project>()
  .Where(project => project.State == pState.state_initiated)
  .SelectMany(project => project.Properties())
  .Where(property => property.Name == "InitiatorName");
```

This is the Interop signature of the Properties Interface:

```
public interface _Properties : IEnumerable
{
    [DispId(1)]
    Application Application { get; }
    [DispId(40)]
    int Count { get; }
    [DispId(2)]
    object Parent { get; }
    [DispId(-4)]
    [TypeLibFunc(1)]
    IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    [DispId(0)]
    Property Item(object index);
}
```

And the Property signature looks like this:

```
public interface Property
{
    [DispId(41)]
    Properties Collection { get; }
    [DispId(40)]
    string Name { get; }
    [DispId(1)]
    Properties Parent { get; }
    [DispId(0)]
    object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your Projects/Project/Property classes as code?

Comment: Can you post error message Linq produce ?

Comment: You didn't show the Project class. How does Project.Properties look like?

Comment: Can you also elaborate on "Find the first Property object"?

Comment: Clarified "First" in the question.

Comment: But you didn't show how `Project.Properties` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
var result = dept.Projects
    .Cast<Project>()
    .Where(project => project.State == pState.state_initiated)
    .SelectMany(project => project.Properties().OfType<Property>())
    .FirstOrDefault(property => property.Name == "InitiatorName");
```

This code is assuming that `Properties` is a method of `Project`.

If it is a property of `Project`, then you need to use `.Properties.OfType<Property>()` instead of `.Properties().OfType<Property>()`.

You might want to use `Cast` instead of `TypeOf` if you are sure that `Properties` only contains objects of type `Property` which is probably the case.

Comment: You've got my vote, but from curiosity, why you picked `OfType` vs `Cast`

Comment: @IvanStoev, OP did not show how `Project.Properties` looks like. But he said "The Properties collection contains Variant/Object/Property objects". So to be safe I assumed that it might contain other types than "Property". It would have been easier if OP showed the `Project` class.

Comment: The posted `_Properties` interface is a typical COM enumerable interface, with `Item` method clearly indicating the expected element type (btw, same can be said for `ControlCollection` and many other WinForms pre generic collections). I personally would use `Cast` to unsure nothing is silently skipped. Anyway, just from academic discussion point :)

Answer (score 0):

By accessing SelectMany of Properties you will not get Projects as required, but properties.

Try this query:

```
var result = dept.Projects
                .Cast<Project>()
                .Where(
                    project =>
                        project.State == pState.state_initiated &&
                        project.Properties().Any(property => property.Name == "InitiatorName"));
```

"Properties()" may not deliver null. So if there is scenario where it could happen please handle the situation by null checking.

Comment: Thanks, looks like Any is the key. I just realized I'm after the first Property object that has the name, not the Projects. I've updated the question (and struck out the original line)